# DataGridView doesn't show data after clone rows

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

Windows form application. C# 4.0.

Basically I have two datagridviews dgv1 and dgv2. One displays the table correctly. I want to select and clone some rows from dgv1 to dgv2 by clicking on the cells in dgv1.

But the second one doesn't show data at all.

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dgv2.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
   private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        DataRowView currentDataRowView = (DataRowView)dgv1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
        DataRow row = currentDataRowView.Row;
        // add row
        dt.ImportRow(row);
        dgv2.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

In debug mode, what I found is that

```
        ?dt.Rows.Count
        1
        ?dt.Columns.Count
        0
        ?dgv2.AutoGenerateColumns
        true
```

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create your columns or copy the schema from another table!

Answer (score 0):

instantiate dt by cloning the datasource of dgv1, ie:

```
datatable dt = otherdatatable.clone()
```

where otherdatatable is the datatable datasource of dgv1